# Multiple instances dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am getting a behavior I don't like and I don't see how to solve it, let's say I have a simple user control with a `DependencyProperty` as follows:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Collection", 
        typeof (ObservableCollection<string>), 
        typeof (TestControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>())); 

public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>) GetValue(CollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
}
```

Then I created 2 diferent instances of this control, notice That I added "Hello" in one control and "World" in the second one, the user control only contains a ItemsControl showing the `DependencyProperty` we created.

```xml
<chartsTest:TestControl Background="Red">
    <chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
        <system:String>hello</system:String>
    </chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
</chartsTest:TestControl>
<chartsTest:TestControl Background="Blue">
    <chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
        <system:String>World</system:String>
    </chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
</chartsTest:TestControl>
```

And I get "Hello World" in both controls:

[image]

I think I understand that this happens because the defualt collection is being initialized as a static variable, ok but then how do I initialize it for each instance?

I know that if I use this sintax it will work:

```xml
<chartsTest:TestControl Background="Blue" x:Name="TestControl" 
                        Collection="{Binding Path=TestProperty}">                
</chartsTest:TestControl>
```

Is there any way to make both work?
I hope I am clear enough, this is a simple example tryin to represent my problem.

Comment: Generally speaking you should definitely use the approach from the last snippet (that is, bind the collection to a view model). Also, you could use an ItemsControl (or base your TestControl in ItemsControl), which will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design, you're not explicitly creating an ObservableCollection so the dependency properties all share the default one you're creating when you register it. There are several ways to solve this but probably the easiest is to to set the default to null and create a wrapper class for ObservableCollection:

```
public class StringObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{
}
```

Then use this in your XAML to wrap your list elements:

```
    <chartsTest:TestControl Background="Red">
        <chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
            <local:StringObservableCollection>
                <system:String>hello</system:String>
            </local:StringObservableCollection>
        </chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
    </chartsTest:TestControl>
    <chartsTest:TestControl Background="Blue">
        <chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
            <local:StringObservableCollection>                  
                <system:String>World</system:String>
            </local:StringObservableCollection>
        </chartsTest:TestControl.Collection>
    </chartsTest:TestControl>
```

Alternatively you can set the value in the constructor as tgpdyk has already pointed out. More details [here](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9986852).

Comment: Btw before asking this I set a new value in the constructor, the problem with that is that you brake bindings to this property

Answer (score 2):

Remember that any DP should be declared as static so the value should be initialized.

On the constructor of your UserControl (TestControl), initialize your Collection property:

Update:

`SetCurrentValue(CollectionProperty, new List<string>());`

We can test it by:

```
<local:TestControl Background="Red">
   <local:TestControl.Collection>
          <system:String>hello</system:String>
    </local:TestControl.Collection>
</local:TestControl>

<local:TestControl Background="Blue">
     <system:String>world</system:String>
</local:TestControl>

<local:TestControl Background="Green" Collection="{Binding List}"/>
```

By the way if you are not listening with item change of your list, I suggest to use a List instead.

Comment: thank you, the problem with this is that you brake the bindings set to the property.

Comment: A minor change would address the problem, see my updated code.